# In nhibernate, when I commit my transaction, the sql update statements don't show in the console. Why?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm getting a little annoyed that the update statements don't show in the console in my nhibernate application when I commit my transactions.

I'm using show_sql = true in the config file. As far as I can tell all the select statements are showing. Updates also show when I'm not using transactions.

Has anyone had this happen to them before? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds weird. Are you using `FlushMode.Commit`? Is the update exec'd but it's just not showing in the output(debug) window?

Comment: FlushMode.Never actually. And yeah the updates are showing in the sql profiler just not the output window.

Comment: Updates can be batched. do you see only some Updates but not all?

Comment: i only see the updates that don't go through the transaction class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is here [NHibernate not showing Update queries with ShowSql enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050930/nhibernate-not-showing-update-queries-with-showsql-enabled)

Just use this config:

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">0</property>
```

Comment: This started showing INSERT, UPDATE and DELETEs for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Fluent NHibernate,

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration
    .MsSql2012
    .ConnectionString(MsSqlDbConnectionString);
    .ShowSql()
    .AdoNetBatchSize(0) // <== to show UPDATE statements
    // etc.
    );
```