# Session Flush not Showing SQL when persisting unsaved entities

Tags: nhibernate, persistence, flush

The scenario is a (more complex) version of the following:

```
IList<T> ts = Session.QueryOvery<T>().List();

// modify data of multiple objects
ts[0].Foo = "foo0";
ts[1].Foo = "foo1";

using (ITransaction trx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
   // save only one object
   Session.Save (ts[0]);
   trx.Commit();
}
```

As NH goes, this will also save `ts[1]` by default, to prevent stale state (side note : we love control over our SQL, so we turn that off by setting `Session.FlushMode=FlushMode.Never`).

What really vexes me is the fact that, even though `Show_SQL` is activated, no sql is shown for the `ts[1]` updates that are definitely sent to the Database by the flush.

Is there any way I can get those to show up?

Comment: this might be of interest : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9403516/1236044

Comment: thanks, jbl. That worked. Could you be so kind to post this as an answer, so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9403516/1236044 , you just need to add `adonet.batch_size` setting with value `0` to your config :

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">0</property>
```